# How to align items to the top of the navbar when a picture increases its size?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have found a couple of similar questions on here, but none of them seemed to exactly answer my problem, tried them all, but nothing worked. (I'm using bootstrap4)

This is my html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
            <div class="container-float">
                    <a class="navbar-brand navbar-left js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top"><img src="{% static 'media/cookie.jpg' %}"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="container-float">
                <button class="navbar-toggler " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">Menu<i class="fas fa-bars ml-1"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Services</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#team">Team</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
</nav>
```

The media/cookie.jpeg file is quite large(the logo for my website), and because of that the whole navbar expands, and the links in the unordered list become vertically aligned to the middle of the navbar. I have tried a bunch of things, including vertical-align:top, but nothing has worked.

How could I align the links to the top of the page/navbar, instead of them being in the middle?

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet

Comment: I'm not quite sure what parts I have to include in order to make it a working snippet, since I have used some template css and html, and don't yet quite understand all that is going on there:/

Comment: create a snippet of your problem exactly the same as your machine have and for snippet creation, you can use codepen.io and for image upload, you can use Imgur.

Comment: But there are over a thousand lines of css, and I don't know which ones to pick out for the snippet

Comment: you need to only put your custom CSS on it else CSS like Bootstrap.css are included in CDN, CDN is online service that provides you whole code in one link and you only need to link it with link tag

Comment: Yep, I understand that, but since I started my project with a template, there are already over a thousand lines of custom CSS

Comment: Does it look like this? https://codepen.io/daniel-knights/pen/VwvmwKy

Comment: @daniel_knights Yes! It does, and the picture is quite big so the items on the right are not aligned with the page top, but rather are centered vertically in the middle.

Comment: https://codepen.io/daniel-knights/pen/VwvmwKy?editors=1100 is this how you want it to look?

Comment: yes, percisely @daniel_knights I also added it to my project and it worked, thank you very much:D If you want to write a short answer as well I can validate it.

Comment: No problem! I wrote out an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use:

```
display: flex;
align-items: flex-start;
```

On the navbar, it will push the links to the top:

https://codepen.io/daniel-knights/pen/VwvmwKy?editors=1100